# Prove that there is a $2 \times 2$-matrix $A$ such that $A + A^2 = E$ and $\det A = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am struggling with the definition of an elementar matrix $E$, how can I use it to prove that there is a $2 \times 2$-matrix $A$ such that $A + A^2 = E$ and $\det A = 0$?

Comment: You can't. $A+A^2=A(I+A)$ has determinant $0$, while elementary matrices are invertible.

Answer (score 1):

If so then $0\cdot\det(I+A)=1$, which is not so true.